# How do I add a high-resolution custom marker on a static google map

Tags: google-maps, retina-display

I'm using Google static maps ([documention here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)) to show shops' locations, and I'm using a custom marker instead of the default.

However, this marker image appears low-resolution on high-resolution mobiles like the iPhone 4.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use high resolution custom markers with the scale parameter in Google's Static Maps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336646/how-can-i-use-high-resolution-custom-markers-with-the-scale-parameter-in-google)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Set `&markers=scale:2` in conjunction with a @2x marker icon image and the `&scale=2` parameter.

I just answered this in a duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130379/378638

Comment: It's working if don't specify size param, but if I specify size param like size:mid, the marker becomes blurry again, thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid the low-resolution dithering, you need to use proportionately larger custom marker images.  See the example below, which references a 64x64 pushpin:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=480x480&markers=icon:**http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/grn-pushpin.png**%7C224+West+20th+Street+NY%7C75+9th+Ave+NY%7C700+E+9th+St+NY&sensor=false

Comment: your demonstration isn't requesting "scale=2" in the url so this isn't accurate. Looks like the same push pin image is used for either and its a bit blurry in the 2x version