# How can I use high resolution custom markers with the scale parameter in Google's Static Maps API?

Tags: retina-display, google-maps-static-api

We're using Google's Static Maps API with the [scale parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#scale_values) to display lovely smooth maps for people using high resolution displays. However, we'd also like to use [custom icons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#CustomIcons) to show points on the map.

Unfortunately I can't find any way of doing this that doesn't give pixelated icons [like in this example](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=100x100&markers=icon:https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE37r.png%7C224%20West%2020th%20Street%20NY%7C75%209th%20Ave%20NY%7C700%20E%209th%20St%20NY&sensor=false&scale=2). Is there a way of doing this that doesn't scale the icons up?

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813143/how-do-i-add-a-high-resolution-custom-marker-on-a-static-google-map ?

Comment: Yup. You'll notice that if you add &scale=2 to the end of that example URL then the icons become pixelated.

Comment: why dont you use your own hd icon versions?

Comment: I'd love to, but when we add the scale parameter to the map the icons get scaled up by the same factor and become pixelated.

Comment: @httpete Sadly not, and I'd still be interested if one was found.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `&markers` parameter now has an (undocumented) `scale` descriptor. Set that to `2` and  the `icon` descriptor to your @2x marker image URL while using the `&scale=2` parameter. Something like:

`&markers=scale:2|icon=icon@2x.png&scale=2`

Source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-api/_METlecmeO4/JNyfkguoO7QJ

Comment: Not works for me. The map is retinified, but marker is not. Here is my url: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=55.73376,37.346275&size=144x144&sensor=true&zoom=12&markers=icon:http://imgur.com/QD06Ctj.png%7C55.73076,37.346275&markers=scale:2|icon=http://imgur.com/OEO1j4V.png&scale=2 , with the http://imgur.com/OEO1j4V.png for retina marker. But the map shows non-retina marker from http://imgur.com/QD06Ctj.png instead...

Comment: @Andrey Your marker image is too small -- imgur.com/OEO1j4V.png needs to be twice the size it currently is without losing image quality.

Comment: @Hakan B., imgur.com/OEO1j4V.png is actually a double-sized retina version, but API just uses non-retina imgur.com/QD06Ctj.png, despite the fact that I appended &markers=scale:2|icon=http://imgur.com/OEO1j4V.png&scale=2 to the end of URL...

Comment: And this is not because of imgur url redirects, I just tested it with self hosting markers on my own server. Seems like this undocumented feature is already gone...

Comment: @Andrey There are some formatting issues with your URL. Try this: https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?&markers=scale:2|icon:http://i.imgur.com/OEO1j4V.png|55.73376,37.346275|&size=144x144&sensor=true&zoom=12&scale=2&

Comment: Oh! I thought that I need to specify both non-retina and retina marker-urls in the final url, and API then will automatically use one or another depending on retina support. Thanks a lot for explaining!

Comment: This worked perfectly for standard icons, thanks!

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=170x96&scale=2&zoom=10&center=Oslo&markers=scale:2|Oslo

Comment: Life saver, but how on earth did you find this undocumented param?

Comment: Nice find, annoying that this is _still_ undocumented and yet required.

Comment: Two years later and this is again, still not documented