# Anyone know how to prevent blurry markers in Google Static Maps?

Tags: google-maps-static-api

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=440x440&scale=2&style=feature:all|element:labels|visibility:off&markers=size:small|scale:2|San+Francisco,CA

Check that out, the marker is blurry when the size is smaller than the default normal. A couple of other questions were asked on here for fixing blurry custom markers and the solution was adding `scale:2` to the URL, however, that does not change anything on the map example above. This is all only when the scale of the map is also set to 2.

Is there a way to make it not so blurry? I'm not using a custom marker, just the default marker that Google provides, so I don't understand why they don't scale with the map very well.

Comment: I have the same problem. Custom markers can only be 64 x 64 pixels and when using scale=2 these markers are blown up to 128 x 128 pixels resulting in a 'blurry' or a pixelated marker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use high resolution custom markers with the scale parameter in Google's Static Maps API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336646/how-can-i-use-high-resolution-custom-markers-with-the-scale-parameter-in-google)

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336646/how-can-i-use-high-resolution-custom-markers-with-the-scale-parameter-in-google

Comment: @bart my markers are not custom. They're the default google markers. I don't understand why they can't keep them clean looking with the also built in scale feature that changes the resolution.

Comment: I see. It requires very little effort to use a custom marker. Go find a marker on Google Images and pop in the URL.